# Is it possible to control the action that Service Fabric takes when a service is 'unhealthy'?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I can see that there are configuration options that allow me to configure the policy that Service Fabric uses to determine whether the cluster is considered to be healthy (based on thresholds for error health reports) but is it possible to get Service Fabric to take some positive action when it detects error health reports, such as restart the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment. You will need to write a service that takes actions based on health.
We are writing a system service that is able to analyze the cluster (including health) and take mitigation steps for problems identified. However, we don't have an estimated date at this time.